# Android / iOS menu buttons

Tags: android, ios

Sorry that I don't have a example code for you to see. My question is that I have 8 image buttons for my menu and I need to know how to make the image buttons show and not show.
Meaning When you go to the menu on Android it shows 7 buttons and hides the 1 button that's for iOS and when your on the iOS it shows all 8 image buttons. I have search on Google for two days now still lost.

Comment: What language is this even in? Are we talking web development? If so, you'll want to look at the User Agent.

Comment: @Anshu Chimala Its coded with html, css, and javascript to be an html menu for a game.

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution for menu buttons: Try this [AwesomeMenu](https://github.com/levey/AwesomeMenu) link.

You will have to make your own modification according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a web app and you need to know if the app is being accessed on an Android device or an iOS device, you should look at the [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string.

Here's a list of iOS devices and their user agent strings: http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/UserAgent (First hit on Google, can't speak for the accuracy).

Here's one for Android devices: http://www.gtrifonov.com/2011/04/15/google-android-user-agent-strings-2/ (again, no idea how accurate; do your own research to be sure).

You just have to look at `navigator.userAgent` in your JavaScript and figure out what device the user is using. That's a start, anyway. (You'll also want to look at the iOS web app documentation to see Apple's specific meta tags and stuff to make your web app work nicely on iOS, and I'm sure Android has something similar).